# selenium webdriver : detect icon with tag name

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a question : how do we detect / find icons by tag name? I have a side pop up menu, only icon is visible. when i hover over icon, how do i get the specific menu item?

`List<WebElement> elementlist = driver.findElements(By.xpath(("//li[@class='MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button']/*[name()='svg']"))); elementlist.get(4).click();`

the code is hard coded. I dont want that. as the menu number of items can vary. i want to get by icon/tag name

[image]
[image]

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
    options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    driver.get("http://testingapp.workspez.com/login");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='field_email']"))).sendKeys("rahul@workspez.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='field_password']")).sendKeys("Sujeet@19");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='MuiButton-label' and contains(., 'Log In')]")).click();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='MuiButton-label' and contains(., 'Operations')]"))).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='MuiButton-label' and contains(., 'View')]"))).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[text()=('Transaction(s)')]"))).click();  
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td[@class='MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body']//button[@class='MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root']/span[@class='MuiIconButton-label']"))).click();
```

Comment: Which icon are you interested to be specific? there are to many items in your website

Comment: i want the middle third one email icon,red in color

Comment: Im saying, if you can attached the `icons` that you interested here in your SO thread, it will be much helpful for me to assist you. I look at the website, but I dont know which icon you interested with despite the id given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, you want to click elements dynamically based on some attributes rather than clicking on 4th webElement in the returned list.

As you have already got the list of elements:

1. you can traverse through it
2. match on the unique attribute of each item
3. once the match is found do a click.

As I can not see the title is present for each element with unique value. You can navigate to your elements like below:

```
List<WebElement> elementlist = driver.findElements(By.xpath(("//li[@class='MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiListItem-gutters MuiListItem-button']/*[name()='svg']")));
```

If you want to click on Email

```
for (int i =0; i<elementlist.size(); i++){
    if (elementlist.get(i).getAttribute("title") == "Email"){
        elementlist.get(i).click();
    }
}
```